# What determines if a character is pinned or 'bounces off' Reinhardt's charge?

Tags: overwatch

I like playing Reinhardt. Charging people is fun, and on basically anyone with less than 400 health it's an instant kill (Assuming you pin them and slam them into a wall).

Sometimes, I seem to collide with enemy players but instead of pinning them... they just 'bounce off' me (I don't really know how else to describe it... they just get knocked far away). This sucks for me, or the Reinhardt... but is pretty great for the player who bounces away since they're no longer closer to an angry Reinhardt. What exactly causes this behavior?

Answer (score 25):

Simply, if you charge directly into an enemy, they won't take any damage and be pinned for the rest of the charge; if you only just graze them, they'll take 50 damage and be knocked back, just like what would happen if you charged into them after pinning another enemy. All of this seems to completely ignore relative height, i.e. there's no vertical graze boundary, and you'll always pin an enemy even if you're just touching their foor or their head, but this scenario is harder to find in regular gameplay.

Imagine, if you will, a spherical Reinhardt, and visualize how enemies' bodies would react to a 200+kg metal ball flying at them. If the enemy were to only touch one side of the sphere, they'd take damage from the hit, of course, but they'd be pushed aside instead of dragged forward. Now if the Reinball were to hit an enemy directly head on, so their body was directly in the way of the center of mass of the sphere, they'd be moved in the same direction as Reinhardt is, dragging them along for the charge. I know it's somewhat of an abstraction, but it works very well to get an idea of how pinning works. I've made a diagram to explain what I mean:

[image: Reinhardt sphere charge]

Of course, this is all based on my experience, but it seems like an accurate model.

Comment: Hm, are you sure it works like that? I feel like this behavior doesn't seem to have a consistent pattern like this (Or perhaps it does, it's just the inherent inaccuracies of an online game make it misleading). If it's not too much trouble, could you maybe provide an overhead diagram of what is considered 'pinned' vs 'grazed'? And do you know if there's a vertical component to that as well? Either way, you've definitely earned a +1 already

Comment: I feel fairly confident saying that, yes. It seems to perfectly model what I've seen both playing as Reinhardt and against him, but that doesn't mean I couldn't be missing something.

Comment: Yes, this also models what I've seen while playing, from closed beta to now. I've been hit in the feet by Reinhardt and been "sucked down" into the pin animation. But, obviously if his model doesn't touch yours, he won't pin you, so there is a vertical limit.

Comment: I suppose in that way, it's more of a cylindrical Reinhardt than a spherical one.

Comment: Of course this simulation and theory only applies to spherical Reinhardts operating within a vacuum, on a flat plane.  Actual performance may have slight variance.

Comment: You get an upvote just for your effort to draw.

Comment: -1 the yellow on your diagram doesn't meet AA standards for color contrast for colorblind accessibility

Comment: ...on a friction-less infinite plane of uniform density.

Comment: Im not convinced. In my experience I am frequently pulled in from the sides and pinned  when it looks like i should he grazed. I can only remember being grazed if another hero is already pinned.

Comment: @Matt Are you saying that being grazed when no other hero is pinned is impossible? Because that's false, and you can easily test it in the practice range.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm sure you are right about being able to be grazed, what I'm saying is that i think the graze range is farther away and smaller than your (super scientific) drawing shows. Maybe  network latency causes it, but i get pulled into the reinhardt charge from what looks like just outside the edge of the spherical reinhardt and rarely if ever get grazed.

Comment: Getting the pin actually doesn't do any damage.  Sometimes this makes it a nuisance, as pinning a low target won't kill them, but grazing them will.  Just some food for thought :-)

Comment: @mpowered Correct, I forgot to edit this some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

The first player you hit is pinned, all subsequent players are knocked back.

Comment: This is certainly true, but I've had many situations where I didn't hit ANYONE at all - everyone just bounced off.

Answer (score 1):

Heyho, 38 hours Reinhard playtime talking here (excluding beta time).
While The partial asnwer of DanmakuGrazer is correct from its content (Describing out of empiric observatiosn aswell), there are additional conditions having influence on this. For example Zarya's shield is reducing the pinning angle. (Untill some days ago, I'd have said her shield makes her unpinable by charging, but then one time I amde it by picking the target completly frontal made me pin her even with shield up.)

Same is true for an transcending Zenyata. Also I had sometimes the feeling (but can't confirm this yet) its harder to pick characters hiding behind a reinhard shield. It everytime felt to me like there it is also mroe likely for them to be bouncing of. So summarized this means, the usual ability blocking kidns of shield affect the zone of getting pinned or just pushed.

Comment: I've never seen what you mention affect the charge in any way.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Just try it before downvoting.

Comment: I did try all of those, I've never seen any difference. As I just mentioned.

Comment: So you did set up it and jsut tryed it all out within 20 minutes after I posted the answer. There are 2 options. you are lying to me now. Or you just assume you tryed it and got it wrong while you were playing it. But in any way. Go on with disrespecting my 5 cents to it thats fine. But my trust into your posts are now zero, as I know you are voting stuff you don't have a clue of.

Comment: You don't have to take this so personally. I see an answer I think is wrong, I downvote it. That's how it works.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Sorry, that was kinda emotion driven. But I played Reinhard quiet a while now. and I'm pretty sure about having been able to pin a shielded zarya only a single time. Just observe it in future games and leave me a note when you know I had been right ;P

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Zarya's bubble does not increase the model's hitbox, so it doesn't make it easier to be pinned, while it looks like it might. I think that's where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Thats what I'll keep an eye on, for the case thats my "confusion" I'll elt you know aswell.